# 4 parameter logistic Law

Tags: terminology, logistic-regression

It is well known that the four parameter logistic law has the following form 
$$ F(x)=D+\frac{A-D}{1+\Big(\frac{x}{C}\Big)^B} $$

What characterise this curve is its four parameters.

A=starting point of the curve.

B= steepness of the curve.

C=inflection point.

D= Maximum asysmptote.

If I am stating the  definition of the parameters  correctly, I am having a doubt about the parameter  $C$. Indeed, if at  $C$ this curve has an inflection point, then by definition of inflection point we must have  $F''(C)=0$ if  $F''$ exists. 
However, we have 
$$ F''(x)= −\frac{B(D−A)(\frac{x}{C})^B\Big((B+1)(\frac{x}{C})^B−B+1\Big)}{x^2\Big((\frac{x}{C})^B+1\Big)^3} $$
 Thus  $F''(C)= −\frac{B(D−A)}{4C^2} \neq  0$

So, what is $C$ ?  Can  $C $ be an inflection point ithout $F''$ being  zero ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After correcting a mistake, I agree with the formula :
$$ F''(x)= −\frac{B(D−A)(\frac{x}{C})^B\Big((B+1)(\frac{x}{C})^B−B+1\Big)}{x^2\Big((\frac{x}{C})^B+1\Big)^3} $$
Anyways $F''(C)\neq0$

This is obvious for low values of $B$. Moreover, there is no inflexion of the curve if $B\leq 1$ : in the formula below, $x_{inflexion}$ is not real.

In fact, saying that $C$ is the abscissa of the inflexion point is an approximate for loosely common use. The inflexion point is the more closer to $x=C$ the more the steepness $B$ is large.

The exact inflexion point is :
$$x_{inflexion}=C \left(\frac{B-1}{B+1} \right)^{\frac{1}{B}}$$

The next graph shows in reduced coordinates the curves for various vales of $B$ and the real position of the inflexion points.

In fact $C$ is the value of $x$ for which $F(x)=\frac{A+D}{2}$ that is exactly the mean of $F(0)$ and $F(\infty)$.

[image]

Comment: In fact, I get the result of the derivative from here http://www.derivative-calculator.net/ . Moreover, till now I haven't see what is $C$ , would you please  add some details?   Why we have no inflection point for  $B\leq 1 $ ?

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake in my calculus. My answer is now corrected, with more details in addition.

Comment: Sorry I have a question, why we have no inflection point for  $B \leq  1$.